# Can Selenium scrape dynamically generated HTML?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to enter email address and click button on this page https://focus.kontur.ru/login. Both email field and button are displayed in my browser and in Chrome inspector, but Selenium does not see them. And there is no trace of them in the HTML code. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to  perform "isEnabled()" or "isDisplayed()" ? From the link, I can see an ID associated to the email textbox - "email". Give it a try by performing findElement on the ID instead of Xpath.

Comment: Which language are you using for this, Javascript? I can try answering in Python.

Comment: Also, add a code of what you tried.

Comment: Hey @Sergey. Please share a code snippet of what you've tried along with a screenshot of the web element inspector for us.